# How to filter aggregations?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have field `tags` *(Integer, multiple=True)*.

I want to aggregate by this field with some filtering (for example, tags in [1, 2, 3]), so only result for tags (1, 2, 3) will return.

Comment: why -1? whats wrong with this question?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html
this link is enough to show how to filter aggregations.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this with a [`filters`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-filter-aggregation.html) aggregation and a `terms` sub-aggregation:

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "tagfilter": {
      "filter": {
        "terms": {
          "tags": [ "1", "2", "3" ]
        }
      },
      "aggs": {
        "mytags": {
          "terms": {
            "field": "tags"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```